Install BLAS 32bit with apt-get in Ubuntu 22.04
I am trying to test a library in a 32 bit system.
In versions before Ubuntu 22.04 I was able to install the 32bit version of BLAS doing this:
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get -y install libblas-dev:i386

However, now I get this error:
E: Unable to locate package libblas-dev:i386

This is strange, because I can still install other 32 bit libraries with no problem, for example sudo apt-get -y install libboost-serialization-dev:i386.
What I am missing?
Could it be that Ubuntu doesn't ship BLAS 32bit anymore, even after adding the i386 architecture.
What alternatives do I have?
(I tried installing other 32 bit implementations of BLAS, such as ATLAS and OpenBLAS, but these 32 bit packages do not exist either).
Here is the full error in a CI machine: https://github.com/correaa/boost-multi/actions/runs/11565598763/job/32192856023#step:3:64

EDIT: I realize that before I was not using Ubuntu, I was using Debian. But when I switched to Github (from Gitlab) the only image available is from ubuntu-latest. https://github.com/actions/runner-images?tab=readme-ov-file#available-images
Still the question remains, why is it not in Ubuntu?
Can I download and install (programmatically) the Debian package and install it the Ubuntu image?

A quick CLI enquiry of package availability shows libblas-dev | 3.10.0-2ubuntu1  | jammy         | amd64, arm64, armhf, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x for jammy or 24.04; ie. it's available for 32-bit ARM and many 64-bit architectures. Only some libraries/packages are built for 32bit x86 (it was identical in 20.04 too if you look; it was built in i386 up to 19.04 only with many builds stopped in 19.10 unless specifically enabled for i386 for future releases in the request process prior during eoan cycle)

Do you know why some packages stop being compiled for i386? because they have irreparable bugs?

@guiverc, see my edit. Can I install the libblas-dev:i386 package from Debian in Ubuntu?

ALL i386 package builds were stopped during the eoan development cycle (early beta), as i386 ISOs were stopped in 2019 and thus there was no need for everything. Much was published about it, and of course feedback from users (esp. those that played games using wine etc) thus specific packages resumed being built as people provided their requirements...  This was done back in 2019; with builds only resuming for packages submitted for inclusion.  It wasn't all 32-bit, as 32-bit ARM wasn't impacted armhf builds of your package exist for focal, jammy & later.. just i386

( there were later i386 ISOs released in 2020 & 2021 and later the the 2019; but all those were respins of older releases, eg. respins of 18.04 in i386, and not new releases...  the stopping of i386 builds related to eoan, focal, groovy & later releases )   You've added Debian details; Debian earlier this year stopped i386 builds too for trixie & later; they just kept building i386 longer than Ubuntu did
